# Return properties of a class who's getters use custom Get method

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a `TransactionData2ClassAction` subclass which looks something like this:

```
  public class TransactionData2ClassAction : Entity
  {
    public int       TransactionId        => Get<int>();
    public int       FundId               => Get<int>();
    public string    PortfolioCode        => Get<string>();
    public string    SecuritySymbol       => Get<string>();
    public string    SecurityTypeCode     => Get<string>();
    public DateTime  TradeDate            => Get<DateTime>();
    public DateTime? SettleDate           => Get<DateTime?>();
    public decimal   Quantity             => Get<decimal>();
    public decimal   Amount               => Get<decimal>();
    public decimal   SecFee               => Get<decimal>();
    public string    BrokerCode           => Get<string>();
    public short     TaxLotNumber         => Get<short>();
    public string    TransactionCode      => Get<string>();
    public decimal   CommissionAmount     => Get<decimal>();

    public int TestProperty { get; }
  }
```

The `Entity` base class looks something like this:

```
public class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
  {
    protected T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string aColumnName = null, DataRowVersion? aDataRowVersion = null)
    {
      // Details.
    }

    protected string Get(CompressionEncryptionOptions aOption, [CallerMemberName] string aColumnName = null)
    {        
      // Details.
    }        
  }
```

My questions is how do I return properties who's getters use either of the `Entity` base class `Get` methods?

For example, the result would return all properties except `TestProperty`.

I have this so far:

```
public static PropertyInfo[] GetTransactionData2FieldsFromEntityUsingProperties(Type aEntityType)
{
  if (!aEntityType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Entity)))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrong type.");

  return aEntityType.GetProperties().Where(aProperty => aProperty.CanRead && aProperty.GetAccessors().Any(aMethodInfo => aMethodInfo.IsAssembly || aMethodInfo.IsPublic)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Mark them with an attribute.. seems reasonable. however you would have to parse the IL to have a reliable solution as to whether a property calls into your base class. i think you might need to rethink this design

Comment: The problem with marking properties with an attribute is that it's not a correlated fact. It would be easy to forget to mark such a property with the right attribute. You could mitigate that with an AOP post-processor (e.g. PostSharp), though.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to constrains I haven't mentioned. I cannot create a new attribute and tag my properties with it.

Comment: If they're not super-secret and you share them, maybe someone will have an idea how to work around them. Still, I think TheGeneral is right, you might need to rethink this design.